# Realtime database on AWS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

Hello, I'm using Google Firebase Real-time Database.
It was so good. On nodejs, react, react-native and etc,
it was nice to be able to handle changes in database values as `event`.

But I wish to develop with Amazon AWS
because I want to know why so many people love AWS and decisively, our company has been supported for 2 years to use AWS.

I wannna implement Realtime database on AWS but I couldn't find information on realtime database on AWS Console.

## Question

1. For Realtime Database with AWS, I think I have to use several features(maybe lambda, dynamoDB). Is it right?
2. On React, NodeJS or etc, can I handle change on database's value?
   (like google firebase cloud function, realtime database)

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer your questions inline.

> 1. For Realtime Database with AWS, I think I have to use several features(maybe lambda, dynamoDB). Is it right?

You can use the newly introduced feature [AWS AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) with different storage optionsthis (e.g DynamoDB or RDS Aurora) where it creates a GraphQL schema and query option making a layer on top of AWS databses for realtime communication with clients. However its still under preview so you need to request it from AWS filling the form.

The other approach is to use AWS APIGateway, Lambda, DynamoDB or Aurora with AWS IOT Websockets.

> 2. On React, NodeJS or etc, can I handle change on database's value? (like google firebase cloud function, realtime database)

Yes both DynamoDB and Aurora provides triggers for change sets to invoke Lambda code.

Answer (score 1):

here is a good comparison of AWS real time db and Google firebase might helpful to you

- https://db-engines.com/en/system/Amazon+DynamoDB%3BFirebase+Realtime+Database%3BRealm